# Applying custom CSS in react for Wordpress' REST API

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress

I have a component along these lines...

```
class AComponent extends React.Component {

state = {
    page: '',
    styleObj:{},
    isLoaded: false
};

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getPageSegment();
}
...
```

where the function `getPageSegment()` is defined as

```
getPageSegment = async () => {
    let response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '<WORDPRESS-SERVER>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/27'
    });
    let page = response.data.content.rendered;
    let styleObj = response.data.customCSS;
    this.setState({
        page: page,
        styleObj: styleObj,
        isLoaded: true
    });
};
```

and the render function is this:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.isLoaded) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.page }} style={this.state.styleObj} />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

I have implemented some wordpress logic to expose the custom CSS via the REST endpoints based on the code [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-css-in-the-rest-api/)

Here is the response from the wordpress REST endpoint:

```
[
    {
    ...
    "content":{
        "rendered":{
            "\n<p class=\"ticss-66b44f07\">111 Lorem ipsum dolor</p>\n\n\n\n<p class=\"ticss-4848221b\">222 Vivamus maximus</p>\n\n\n\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image size-large is-resized ticss-0fcb86c1\"><img loading=\"lazy\" src=\"https://i2.wp.com/www.downshiftology.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Cobb-Salad-3.jpg\" alt=\"Image of cob salad. Bacon, geggs, avocado slices etc.\" width=\"512\" height=\"342\"/><figcaption>cob salad image</figcaption></figure>\n"
        }
    }
    ...
    "customCSS": ".ticss-66b44f07 {background: #999;} .ticss-4848221b {background: #ddd;  font-size:2rem;  padding: 50px;} .ticss-0fcb86c1 img {    border-radius: 10px;}",
    ...
    }
]
```

When I apply the style object as above, I get the following error:

```
Error: The 'style' prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string
```

I understand the error. How can I apply the class defined in customCSS dynamically to the usage of the said class in the page when it's rendered by react?

Comment: You set the `isLoaded` to `true` initially. Shouldn't it be `false`? I think it should be set to true only after style object is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.Sorry! I hadn't added the initialization part of the code in the question above though it was there in my code. Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

JSX style attribute accepts a json object containing CSS properties and values.

Typically you would pass class names and attributes like this

```
<div style={{myStyles}}) className="ticss-0fcb86c1"/>
```

Where
styles is a JSON are written as

```
const mystyle = {
      backgroundColor: "#ddd",
      fontSize: "2em",
      padding: "50px",
    };
```

Note that

- Style name is converted from background-color to background-Color, font-size is written as fontSize and so on..
- Class is specified as 'className'
- Individual html element is assigned a class.

You are getting an error because style variable is a string, not JSON object.

You can possibly try to go over all the individual html elements and add styles, but I wouldn't recommend.